# How can I split the list elements and replace them based on a space delimiter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to split the elements of a `list` that I have, based on a space delimiter and replace the string that I am splitting with the newly split string.

So far I have tried this, I have used `split` function to split the string, but I am unable to append the split elements (or string) back to my original list.
I tried using `join` on the list items, but that gave me a syntax error.

Here is what i tried so far:

```py
my_list = [
    'my_label2 new_label2 my_label',
    'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3',
    'my_label2 new_label2 my_label'
]

for item in my_list:
    if ' ' in item:
        print(True)
        my_list.append(i)
        print(i)
    else:
        print(False)

print(my_list)
```

But my code does not give me the expected result.
The resultant `list` that I am getting is:

```py
['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label', ['my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label'], ['label_test1', 'label_test2', 'label_test3'], ['my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label']]
```

But what I am actually trying to get is something like this:

**original list:**

```
['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label']
```

**new list:**

```
['my_label2', 'new_label2',  'my_label', 'label_test1', 'label_test2, 'label_test3', 'my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label']
```

Comment: You should never mutate or modify a list while looping through it. Always create a new list and leave the old list as it is.

Answer (score 3):

Using `str.split` with `chain.from_iterable`

**Ex**

```
from itertools import chain
my_list = ['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label']
print(list(chain.from_iterable(i.split() for i in my_list)))
```

**Output:**

```
['my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label', 'label_test1', 'label_test2', 'label_test3', 'my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label']
```

Answer (score 2):

[extend()](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/list/extend)- is used to merge two lists or insert multiple elements in one list.

[split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.split) - returns a list of strings after breaking the given string by the specified separator. by default, split() takes whitespace as the delimiter.

```
my_list = ['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label']
new_list=[]
for elm in my_list:
    new_list.extend(elm.split(" "))

print(new_list)
```

O/P:

```
['my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label', 'label_test1', 'label_test2', 'label_test3', 'my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label']
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
import itertools

my_list = ['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label']

new_list = itertools.chain(*[l.split() for l in my_list])
print(list(new_list))  # >> ['my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label', 'label_test1', 'label_test2', 'label_test3', 'my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label']
```

`chains`, from the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) builtin library, allow you to chain 2+ iterables into one.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
>>> my_list = ['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label']
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> [j for i in my_list for j in i.split()]

['my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label', 'label_test1', 'label_test2', 'label_test3', 'my_label2', 'new_label2', 'my_label']
```

Comment: this works in the command prompt for me, but not inside my python script.

Comment: the output is the same list passed

Comment: @PDoe Have copy and pasted the code? Instead of `j` if you use `i` then only you will get same list.

Answer (score 1):

This piece can give the result but it is the best way to do it?

```
my_list = ['my_label2 new_label2 my_label', 'label_test1 label_test2 label_test3', 'my_label2 new_label2 my_label']
new_list = []
for item in my_list:
    new_list.extend(item.split())
my_list.clear()
my_list.extend(new_list)
print(my_list)
```